# Improving query performance in MYSQL with a lot of subqueries

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new to MYSQL and in general writing queries.
the most important things in this query is cycle_count_id and location. all information should be based on this two factors.
now, how can I improve this query:

```
SELECT c2.code_cycle_count, c2.location, c2.last_cyclecount, c2.second_recent_cyclecount ,i.uid,c2.po_number, i.cost, i.uid


   , (SELECT
      CASE WHEN MAX(cc.updated_at) = MAX(ccc.updated_at) THEN u.username ELSE NULL END
      from oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count ccc
    INNER JOIN oms_live_ir.ims_user u ON u.id_user=ccc.fk_user
      WHERE ccc.fk_location = cc.fk_location AND ccc.id_cycle_count=cc.id_cycle_count) AS cycle_count_user



   , (SELECT  COUNT(cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status)

    from oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count_item cci
    WHERE cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status = 1 AND cc.id_cycle_count=cci.fk_cycle_count) AS location_updated

  , (SELECT  COUNT(cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status)
    from oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count_item cci
    WHERE cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status = 2 AND cc.id_cycle_count=cci.fk_cycle_count) AS status_updated


  , (SELECT  COUNT(cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status)
    from oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count_item cci
    WHERE cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status = 4 AND cc.id_cycle_count=cci.fk_cycle_count) AS found

  , (SELECT  COUNT(cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status)
    from oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count_item cci
    WHERE cci.fk_cycle_count_item_status = 6 AND cc.id_cycle_count=cci.fk_cycle_count) AS lost

  , c5.id_pick, c5.date_pick


  FROM oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count cc
  INNER JOIN oms_live_ir.wms_inventory i on i.fk_location=cc.fk_location



  INNER join
    (SELECT l.description AS location
  ,MAX(cccc.id_cycle_count) AS code_cycle_count
  ,MAX(cccc.updated_at) AS last_cyclecount, i.po_number
  ,(SELECT MAX(c1.updated_at) FROM oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count c1 WHERE c1.updated_at<>MAX(cccc.updated_at)
  AND c1.fk_location=cccc.fk_location) as second_recent_cyclecount

   FROM oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count cccc
  INNER JOIN oms_live_ir.wms_inventory i ON i.fk_location=cccc.fk_location
  INNER JOIN oms_live_ir.ims_location l ON l.id_location=cccc.fk_location

   WHERE year(cccc.updated_at)>=2018 AND month(cccc.updated_at)>=1
   AND LEFT(i.po_number,2) LIKE 'M1%' or LEFT(i.po_number,2) LIKE 'S1%'
     GROUP by cccc.fk_location
   ) c2 on c2.code_cycle_count= cc.id_cycle_count

INNER JOIN
(SELECT  cc5.fk_location, 
          (SELECT CASE WHEN ih2.updated_at=MIN(ih2.updated_at) THEN ih2.sales_order_item_id ELSE NULL END
           FROM oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count cc2
            INNER JOIN oms_live_ir.wms_inventory_history ih2 ON ih2.fk_location=cc2.fk_location
            WHERE ih2.sales_order_item_id=ih5.sales_order_item_id AND ih2.fk_location=cc5.fk_location AND cc2.id_cycle_count=cc5.id_cycle_count
            AND year(ih2.updated_at)>=2018 AND MONTH(ih2.updated_at)>=1 AND ih2.sales_order_item_id IS NOT NULL 
            GROUP BY ih2.id_inventory) id_pick
          ,(SELECT CASE WHEN ih2.updated_at=MIN(ih2.updated_at) THEN ih5.updated_at ELSE NULL END
            FROM oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count cc2
            INNER JOIN oms_live_ir.wms_inventory_history ih2 ON ih2.fk_location=cc2.fk_location
            WHERE ih2.sales_order_item_id=ih5.sales_order_item_id AND ih2.fk_location=cc5.fk_location AND cc2.id_cycle_count=cc5.id_cycle_count
            AND year(ih2.updated_at)>=2018 AND MONTH(ih2.updated_at)>=1 AND ih2.sales_order_item_id
            GROUP BY ih2.id_inventory) date_pick

          FROM oms_live_ir.wms_cycle_count cc5
          INNER JOIN oms_live_ir.wms_inventory_history ih5 ON ih5.fk_location=cc5.fk_location
 WHERE year(ih5.updated_at)>=2018 AND MONTH(ih5.updated_at)>=1 AND ih5.sales_order_item_id IS NOT NULL) c5 ON c5.fk_location=cc.fk_location



    WHERE year(cc.updated_at)>=2017 AND month(cc.updated_at)>=1
  AND LEFT(i.po_number,2) LIKE 'M1%' or LEFT(i.po_number,2) LIKE 'S1%'
group by c2.code_cycle_count, c2.location;
```

(Note: I do not have access to create temporary tables or create index for tables.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There are two spots where you call `AND LEFT(i.po_number,2) LIKE 'M1%' or LEFT(i.po_number,2) LIKE 'S1%'` The `LEFT` function should only return 2 characters, so then using `LIKE` with a wildcard in the third character location is redundant. `LIKE` is an expensive operation, so swapping those out for `=` might net you a small performance gain. I would try taking a look at the query plan, and see where the most expensive operations are. That should give you some better insight as to where optimization is going to give you the most bang for your buck.